# Where is the sqlite3 database stored on the iphone emulator?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, emulation

Now that I have a read-only application working, I am working on the insert statement.  The insert returned OK in my code, but the read-back (in the code) came up empty, so I want to use the command line or browser to read.  Can I copy the DB off the emulator and into my laptop for access with other utilities?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access the documents directory of your app at `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<SDK VERSION>/Applications/<SOME RANDOM HASH>/Documents`

Note that the SDK version will be different depending on what you are building under, and the hash is tough to figure out which one is yours.  Just inspect the folders and look for a `YOURAPP.app` binary to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks --- I found about 100+ now to find my current one.

Comment: just a suggestion for others: if you delete all your other apps from you simulator (or at least the ones you don't need) the it is quicker to find your app in the hash codes

Comment: Any chance it moved in XCode 4.5? Can't find "iPhone Simulator" under "Application Support"

Comment: Assuming you just installed your app, use "ls -lt" to sort by date, and yours will be the first.

Answer (score 0):

What database?
Assuming you have created it in your app's documents folder, app sandboxes for the simulator are in `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<version>/<uuid>`, and contain the application and it's Documents, Library and tmp directories.